# Accessing a method that has to print a data member using an object pointer of a class

Tags: c++

I have got the following code and I got an unexpected result
does anybody know why that happened??!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A2
{
public:

    void disp ()
    {
        cout<<m<<endl;
    }
private:
    int m = 4;//this is the data member I want to show
};

int main()
{
    A2 al;
    al.disp();// the output of this is 4
    A2 *a2;

    a2->disp(); 
    //here is the unexpected result, I think that it should be 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where does `a2` point to?

Comment: Declaration of a pointer-to-`some_type` does not create any object of that `some_type` by itself. Such an uninitialized pointer may not be dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

`a2` here is just uninitialized. You must make `a2` point to the object and then call the function.

```cpp
A2* a2 = &al; // points to a1
a2->disp();
```

Or

```cpp
A2* a2 = new A2(); // constructs another A2 objcet and points to
a2->disp();
delete a2;
```

More about pointers, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: it is not a `nullptr`. It is uninitialized

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, my bad. an uninitialized pointer can point to anywhere.

Comment: the pointer 'a2' is uninitialized, so its members is also initialized, i.e., the value "4" is never assigned to its member 'm' 

edit: rephrase, contructor has nothing to do with it

Comment: @stribor14 there is no absolute relationship between pointer initialization and pointed object initialization. You can initialize a pointer to an uninitialized object.

Answer (score -1):

In your line:

```cpp
A2 *a2;
```

You have to complete with:

```
A2 *a2 = new A2();
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, Nimrod makes the same answer faster than you. So why do you still post this answer?

Comment: This is a nice sideremark, but the actual answer is missing here

Comment: I hadn't seen it when I posted